# How to send relational data from multiple foreach to view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I made a Laravel project where Category, Subcategory and Child category working using same table relation.
I want to show all products from childcategory when click to Main Category.
So for that I need to use multiple foreach loop like this,

```
foreach ($categories->subcategories as $subcat)
{
foreach ($subcat->childcategories as $childcat )
{
$products = $childcat->products;
}
}
```

Now I want to send $products to a view. How can I do it.
I don't want to use array. How can I send It. Please help.

Comment: You can pass the `$categories` to your view and loop through it exactly the same way using [blade syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops).

Comment: If you have relationships set up, [use eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Comment: But problem is I can't use pagination for product.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - eager loading has nothing to do with pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Array()

```
$products = array()
foreach ($categories->subcategories as $subcat)
{
foreach ($subcat->childcategories as $childcat )
{
     $products[] = $childcat->products;
}
}
return view(....);
```

Comment: I did it but then I can't sort product like Eloquent Collection.

Comment: I learn a way to sort array using collect() method. So now I don't need to send products directly to view. I can use array what you suggest in your answer and can sort like this              
   $child = collect($child)->sortBy('price')->reverse()->toArray();                                              So I accepted your Answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel you can pass your Category Object to the view. In Blade you have access to the relationships of Category. You can testet by :

`dd($categories->subcategories)` or `dd($categories->subcategories[]->childcat)`.

Comment: But problem is I can't use pagination for product if I do this.

Comment: @AbirHusain Of course you can also do this via paginate :-)

Comment: Can you please explain how can I paginate products If I send Categories to the view. Because If I send $products object with paginate () method then I can use $products->links() for pagination in view. How Can I do this if I send Category object ?

Comment: @AbirHusain this is a completely new question. your question above was: "How to send relational data from multiple foreach to view in Laravel". The best thing to do is to ask a completely new question, but first think about what other difficulties might arise and define your new question accordingly. That makes more sense than debugging your code here in the comments ;-)

Comment: Thank you for reply.But your answer was not related to my questions. I don't need to use foreach loop If I want to send Categories. I want to send $products from multiple foreach.

Comment: @AbirHusain I see. That was not quite clear to me. Question: In this case, what prevents you from calling up the product model in the controller and sending it? `Product::paginate(10)`.